# How do I subtract two integers without knowing their values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm doing this Python exercise and the directions are: Define a function calls subtractNumber(x, y) that takes in two numbers and returns the difference of the two numbers.

Examples

```
>>> subtractNumber(20, 7)
13
>>> subtractNumber(-20, -4)
-16
>>> subtractNumber(-2, -2)
0
```

My code

```
def subtractNumber(x, y): 
    subtraction = int(x) - int(y)
    return subtraction
subtractNumber('x','y')
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Exercises\Temp_Learning\Python Practice9.py", line 4, in <module>
    subtractNumber('x','y')
  File "D:\Python Exercises\Temp_Learning\Python Practice9.py", line 2, in subtractNumber
    subtraction = int(x) - int(y)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'
```

I still don't understand where I went wrong.  Can someone help me, please?  Thanks.

Comment: You ask python to cast the string ```x``` as integer. What do you expect there?

Comment: ...is your function supposed to subtract numbers or strings? Why are you giving it strings as input? And what's the whole "subtract numbers without knowing their values" thing about? How can you not know the value of a number? Are you trying to do symbolic math, like sympy?

Answer (score 0):

`int` is something used to convert something into an integer.

```
x = '5'
y = int(x)
```

would result in `y` having the value `5`

`int(x)` when `x=5` return `5`. However, you sent in the character `'x'` to `int`. `int` does not know how to convert that to an integer.

This should work for you

```
In [3]: def subtractNumber(x, y):
   ...:     return (int(x) - int(y))
   ...:

In [4]: subtractNumber(5, -6)
Out[4]: 11

In [5]: subtractNumber(5, 6)
Out[5]: -1

In [6]: subtractNumber(-5, 6)
Out[6]: -11

In [7]: subtractNumber(-5, -6)
Out[7]: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your example, `'x'` and `'y'` are strings that don’t represent a number, therefore they can’t be converted using `int()`.**

So you can't do that:

```
subtractNumber('x', 'y')
```

However, these would work:

```
>>> subtractNumber(13, 7) # Regular integers
13
>>> subtractNumber('13', '7') # Strings that contain digits can be converted to int
13
>>> x = 13
>>> y = 7
>>> subtractNumber(x, y) # Here, x and y are variables, not strings
13
```

Answer (score 0):

`'x'` and `'y'` are not numbers, but strings. What number would you assume the character x and the character y to be?

If you want to use previously assigned variables, just pass `x` and `y`:

```
subtractNumber(x, y)
```

If you want to use the ascii char code behind both letters use:

```
subtractNumber(ord('x'), ord('y'))
```